# R Programming convert string to numeric

Tags: r, string, numeric

I have a dataset from that website;
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aliibrahim10/valorant-stats/code?datasetId=2177984 . And I have a problem.

I have a dataset which includes numeric values but because of the some values has comma separtor for thousands ( "1,200") it shows as a character variable. When we try to solve this problem with that code:
deaths_num <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",nim$deaths,fixed=TRUE))

But, it delete some our values and we need that values ( for example we have 1,472 before the code, after we run the code it delete and shows NA instead of 1472). How can we solve it? Can you help me?

Comment: `as.data.frame(apply(x, 2L, \(i) if( all(grepl("[0-9,.]", i)) ) gsub(",", "", i) else i))`?

Comment: Can you explain me these code please?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem `nim = read.csv("/Users/blabla/Downloads/val_stats.csv"); l = as.numeric(gsub(",", "", nim$deaths)); l[which(nim$deaths == "1,472")]` works on my machine.

Comment: You can use the `dplyr` package to remove commas then convert the comma-free character to numeric: `library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(val1 = c("1,234","1,235","1,236"))

str(dat)

dat <- dat %>% mutate(val2 = as.numeric(gsub(",","",.$val)))

str(dat)`